# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#9d579 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Tags: flutter, dart, global-state

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TaskTile> createState() => _TaskTileState();
}

class _TaskTileState extends State<TaskTile> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  // void checkboxCallback(bool checkboxState) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     isChecked = checkboxState;
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        'This is a task.',
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
      ),
      trailing: TaskCheckbox(
          checkboxState: isChecked,
          toggleCheckboxState: (bool checkboxState) {
            setState(() {
              isChecked = checkboxState;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}

class TaskCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool checkboxState;
  final Function toggleCheckboxState;

  const TaskCheckbox(
      {required this.checkboxState, required this.toggleCheckboxState});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      value: checkboxState,
      onChanged: toggleCheckboxState(),
    );
  }
}
```

As per the concept of Global state. I'm trying to use my bool isChecked value for both checkbox and checkbox title which is text. But i get the blue blank in my android emulator. I'm new to flutter and don't know exactly what went wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

*"Will edit later to add explanation, running out of time"*

This update code should work:

```
class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const TaskTile({super.key});

  @override
  State<TaskTile> createState() => _TaskTileState();
}

class _TaskTileState extends State<TaskTile> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  // void checkboxCallback(bool checkboxState) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     isChecked = checkboxState;
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        'This is a task.',
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
      ),
      trailing: TaskCheckbox(
        checkboxState: isChecked,
        toggleCheckboxState: (bool? checkboxState) {
          setState(() {
            isChecked = checkboxState!;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TaskCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool checkboxState;
  final Function(bool?) toggleCheckboxState;

  const TaskCheckbox(
      {super.key,
      required this.checkboxState,
      required this.toggleCheckboxState});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      value: checkboxState,
      onChanged: toggleCheckboxState,
    );
  }
}
```